# How to profile Entity Framework activity against SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-profiler

It's easy to use SQL Server Profiler to trace stored procedures activity. But how to trace SQL queries issued by LINQ via Entity Framework? I need to identify such queries (LINQ code) that consume a lot of time, are called most frequently and therefore are the first candidates for optimization.

Comment: You can definitely still use SQL Server Profiler to see what's happening on the ultimate backend, or check out [Entity Framework Profiler](https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof) to inspect the EF code directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found useful `DbContext.Database.Log` property.

MSDN article [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464.aspx)

The `DbContext.Database.Log` property can be set to a delegate for any method that takes a string. Most commonly it is used with any `TextWriter` by setting it to the “Write” method of that TextWriter. All SQL generated by the current context will be logged to that writer. For example, the following code will log SQL to the console:

```
using (var context = new BlogContext())
{
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write;

    // Your code here...
}
```

**What gets logged?**

When the Log property is set all of the following will be logged:

- The approximate amount of time it took to execute the command. Note that this is the time from sending the command to getting the result object back. It does not include time to read the results.
- SQL for all different kinds of commands. For example:
  Queries, including normal LINQ queries, eSQL queries, and raw queries from methods such as SqlQuery
- Inserts, updates, and deletes generated as part of SaveChanges
- Relationship loading queries such as those generated by lazy loading
- Parameters
- Whether or not the command is being executed asynchronously
- A timestamp indicating when the command started executing
- Whether or not the command completed successfully, failed by throwing an exception, or, for async, was canceled
- Some indication of the result value

Answer (score 7):

Add this key to your connection string:

```
Application Name=EntityFramework
```

And filter by this in Profiler

Comment: Thank you.Will Profiler identify concrete LINQ statement/query that consume most of the calls/time? Entity framework is the only way to access SQL Server in this application. That is - is there way to map line in Profiler to LINQ line in application code?

Comment: Profiler logs time/resources consumed, yes, You can use Database.Log (requires config/code changes) to log in code...

Comment: Unfortunately our project uses ObjectContext - likely you mentioned about Database.Log Property and setting this property to log the SQL generated by the DbContext to the given delegate?

Answer (score 2):

Adding @ErikEJ's answer : if you are using **.net Core**, so you are using EFCore. There are no **Database.Log** property. You should use **OnConfiguring** override of your DbContext class and then

```
optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
```

Sample :

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }       

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```